# Android phone under 15000 Rupees Indian currency ($250)

Tags: android

I would like to buy an Android phone for gaming under 15000 rupees ($250). The budget can be increased slightly if the phone has better features.

- I would like to play Player Unknown's Battlegrounds(PUBG), Clash of Clans, Clash Royale, Instagram, Facebook, WhatsApp
- Performance for medium graphics gaming or higher
- Type-C port
- Good battery life (4000 mAh)
- 2 sim, 1 SD Card port, non hybrid sim.
- Android 8, Full HD Display
- Able to purchase in India

Any suggestions with the specifications are most welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my needs honor play was the best in 250$ and satisfied most my needs.